# Getting polygon coordinates for areas outside known polygons using R

Tags: r, sf, sp, maptools

I have downloaded [shapefile containing polygons for urban areas](https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/grump-v1-urban-extents/data-download). However, I am interested in polygons representing rural areas. Therefore I would like to convert the shapefile containing urban areas polygons to rural areas using R. Thus an inverse of it. My assumption is that areas can either be rural or urban.

I have tried the following;

```
urban_poly <- read_sf(global_urban_extent_polygons_v1.01.shp)

rural_poly <- invert_poly(urban_poly)
```

Comment: Because the two-dimensional flat coordinate space that we do most GIS in is infinite, the "invert" of a set of polygons is an infinite space, and that's not well representable in the model we have. If you have a finite bounds (and this might be "rest of the world") then you can construct a polygon for that and do an `st_difference`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using UN mapping data, they provide a few different datasets and may already have a map that shows what you need: https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Training_Material_for_UN_Open_GIS_OpenData#Preparing_the_geospatial_data